# API gateway and service discovery on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices

I'm trying to build an application infrastructure on Amazon AWS following a microservice pattern.

However the configuration API gateway and service discovery tool together completely puzzles me.

According to [a pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) I need both (and I understand that). I decided to go with [Amazon API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) as API gateway and [Hashicorp Consul](https://www.consul.io/) as service discovery.

From what I see in the configuration guide on Amazon, API gateway configuration is pretty much straightforward: I specify path and URL to follow and that's it.

How in the world do I explain API gateway to get information from Consul?

PS. There is a [Consul quickstart](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/consul/) guide, but it is just a deployment instruction. There is nothing about connecting it to the API gateway.

Comment: Isn't it better to use Netflix API Gateway (deployed on Ec2 instance) that works perfect with Consul or Netflix Service Registry. That way we can get advantage of dynamic service lookup + client side load balancing (ribbon or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is no existing solution for such a configuration.

I have to develop something on my own.

A nice source for help might be a series of articles on [the Amazon developer blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/serverless-service-discovery-part-1-get-started/) and [REST API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-rest-api.html) for the Amazon API gateway service.